# Adding breezeJS to my Ionic Project Fails with White Screen on install on device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, breeze

I have a need project the i want to use breezeJS, My ionic project works fine, but when i add breezeJS as dependence to the ionic angular.module, On my chrome carnary and on emulator it works fine, but when i install it on my device i get a white screen.

Is there anything that am missing, Please i need the community help to get this fix.

HTML:

```
<script src="scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/breeze.angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/breeze.directives.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/breeze.saveErrorExtensions.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ionic',
'starter.controllers',
'starter.services',
'LocalStorageModule', // Angular Local Storage

//// Custom modules 
'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner

///This is where i get the error, but when i remove this part the project works fine
'breeze.angular',    // configures breeze for an angular app
'breeze.directives', // contains the breeze validation directive (zValidate)
])

// Handle routing errors and success events
app.run(['$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', 'breeze',
function ($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, breeze) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }
    });
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will appreciate if i can get a sample code, that demostrate how the dependency works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After so many testing and research, i later get it to work,

The issue is with breeze.debug:

```
<script src="scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
```

I removed it so am left with

```
<script src="script/breeze.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/labs/breeze.angular.js"></script>
```

The app.js file will be

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ionic', 
  'starter.controllers', 
  'starter.services',

  'breeze.angular'    // configures breeze for an angular app
])
```

That resolve the issues.

Thanks.